# Python3 Data Impute

Tags: python-3.x

Job interview that I bombed on.

```
    Remove all rows where at least half of the entries are negative
    Fill in remaining negative values in each column with the 
    average for that column, excluding invalid entries
```

```
Input: [[5],
     [3],
     [1.0, 2.0, 10.0],
     [-1.0, -99.0, 0],
     [-1.0, 4.0, 0],
     [3.0, -6.0, -0.1],
     [1.0, -0.31, 6.0]
    ]

Output: new mean rounded to one decimal place
```

Not sure where to start

Output new mean rounded to one decimal place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are 3 columns and there's 1 or none negative value in each remaining column that are being replaced by the average of the entire column.

Then:

```
np = [[5],[3],[1.0,2.0,10.0],[-1.0,-99.0,0],[-1.0,4.0,0],[3.0,-6.0,-0.1],[1.0,-0.31, 6.0]]
cols = 0  # save num of cols for later
for l in inp:
    pos = 0  # count positive
    neg = 0  # count negative
    for n in l:
        if n > 0:
            pos += 1  # update
        elif n < 0:
            neg += 1  # update
    if pos+neg > cols:  # save num of cols
        cols = pos+neg
    if pos < neg:  # remove list with too many negatives
        inp.remove(l)

for i in range(cols):  # loop through cols
    neg_index = 0  # find the negative value's index to replace with the average
    entries = 0  # for calculating the average
    summ = 0  # for calculating the average
    for c in inp:
        try:  # see if col exist in a list
            if c[i] < 0:
                neg_index = inp.index(c)  # save index of negative value found
            else:
                summ += c[i]
                entries += 1
        except:
            continue
    try:  # see if col exist in list
        inp[neg_index][i] = round(summ / entries,1)  # replace negative value index with average
    except:
        continue

print(inp)
```

Result:

```
[5],
[3],
[1.0, 2.0, 10.0],
[2.5, 4.0, 0],
[1.0, 3.0, 6.0],
```

I believe this is what they were looking for, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's working correctly. By I cannot calc the mean from the final array. I converted it to a numpy array and ran numpy.mean(inp). I get **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'**.

Comment: numpy.mean(...) is trying to divide a list from an int, which is not possible. This is because the lists are different sizes. Check out this post, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058227/calculating-mean-of-arrays-with-different-lengths